# How to import a third party certificate on multiple AWS instances managed by a load balancer?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

I have an app which is registered with a third party Identity Provider(Azure Active Directory). I am implementing Single Sign On using SAML 2.0. For this to work, I have to import a certificate file provided by Azure and import it on my local machine in a keystore. I also need to generate a private key against the same keystore. Everything is working well on my machine.
Now i am not sure where to install these certificates on AWS. I would be having a Load balancer to create multiple instances. So my confusion is where to add this certificate so that all my instances would have this certificate installed.

Answer (score 0):

you need to import your ssl certificate in AWS Certificate Manager, then you can use it to terminate ssl in your AWS Load balancer, here is a guide to import third party ssl certificate in ACM, [Link](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/acm/latest/userguide/import-certificate-api-cli.html#import-certificate-api)

Comment: can you elaborate what do you mean by to terminate ssl in your AWS Load balancer.

Comment: It means to use your imported ssl certificate to configure https listener in the AWS ALB